# Is it possible to create a Javascript version of UUID generator equivalent to Java's

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, uuid

Is it possible to create a javascript version of UUID generator equivalent to Java's `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes("Hello world".getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8))`. Is there anything available for Javascript or Jquery.

It should return the exact UUID for an input string for both Java and Javascript versions. Here is the Java version of doing it, https://ideone.com/GYvxCE for reference.

Please help.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but what you're asking is too broad because you are asking for software/library recommendations.

Comment: thank you, bro. @zero298

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505620/javas-uuid-nameuuidfrombytes-to-written-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you guys, for your help. I modified solution provided by @Akrion and it worked for me.

The modified solution is below.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hexToUuid = require('hex-to-uuid');

const java_kind_hash = (input) => {
    var md5Bytes = crypto.createHash('md5').update(input).digest()
    md5Bytes[6] &= 0x0f;  // clear version 
    md5Bytes[6] |= 0x30;  // set to version 3 
    md5Bytes[8] &= 0x3f;  // clear variant 
    md5Bytes[8] |= 0x80;  // set to IETF variant
    return hexToUuid(md5Bytes.toString('hex'))
}

console.log('java_kind_hash ', java_kind_hash ("HelloWorld"));
    // 68e109f0-f40c-372a-95e0-5cc22786f8e6
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Look like this package has methods similar to what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you, @balzee. I've tried the package but it is not satisfying my needs. I need a javascript version of the UUID generator which is an exact equivalent to Java UUID for the same input string. Any further help would be greatly appreciable.