# nameUUIDFromBytes in sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've used [UUID.html#nameUUIDFromBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[])). I'd like to run the same logic on a column in table x. Are there any options for doing this in a sql query, ideally one that BigQuery supports?

I'm unable to modify the data in table x. Additionally table x is quite large and I'd rather not put in the resources to write a pipeline to copy it to another table y (using the java function in the pipeline) if I could do this in sql.

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs and outputs?  Your link does not provide much context.

Comment: Could you test if JavaScript approach here generates same results as Java libray: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505620/javas-uuid-nameuuidfrombytes-to-written-in-javascript ? If it works, you can create a JavaScript UDF in BigQuery to leverage the js code.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT GENERATE_UUID() AS uuid;
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/uuid_functions#generate_uuid

Source thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49438112/11928117

Comment: Could you provide with some example code of what you would like to run on Cloud BigQuery or, as rtenha mentioned, some input/output sample to provide more context?